# Spark | pyspark with fbprophet - parallel processing not working with rdd.map

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, rdd, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to implement fbprophet with pyspark, but can't paralelize the code on all available cores (running it locally on my machine).

I have already searched for a variety of articles trying to understand why this is happening.

Below you can find the chunk of code where the parallelization should happen. I had already defined all the mapped functions

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

conf = (SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .setAppName("SparkFBProphet Example"))

spark = (SparkSession
         .builder
         .config(conf=conf)
         .getOrCreate())

# Removes some of the logging after session creation so we can still see output
# Doesnt remove logs before/during session creation
# To edit more logging you will need to set in log4j.properties on cluster
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

# Retrieve data from local csv datastore
print(compiling_pickle())
df = retrieve_data()

# Group data by app and metric_type to aggregate data for each app-metric combo
df = df.groupBy('column1', 'column2')
df = df.agg(collect_list(struct('ds', 'y')).alias('data'))


df = (df.rdd
      .map(lambda r: transform_data(r))
      .map(lambda d: partition_data(d))
      .map(lambda d: create_model(d))
      .map(lambda d: train_model(d))
      .map(lambda d: make_forecast(d))
      .map(lambda d: imp_predictions(d))
      .saveAsTextFile("../data_spark_t/results"))

spark.stop()
```

In this section:

```
print(compiling_pickle())
df = retrieve_data()
```

A pickle is loaded, compiled and a csv is generated. With the retrieve function i only do this:

```
df = (spark.read.option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", value=True)
      .csv("../data_spark_t/database_created.csv"))
```

So, with all this i'm not understanding why my code is not attaching all available cores on the execution.

Just to point some already tested points:

- My paritition number is 500. I have already set this equal to the number of rows in df (after 'collect_list') but didn't work;
- All possible combinations to setMaster() have been implemented;

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("column 1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("column 2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("column 3", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("yhat", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("yhat_lower", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("yhat_upper", FloatType(), True),
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema)
df.write.options(header=True).csv(
    'dbfs:/mnt/location/output_teste_1', mode='overwrite')
```

Just needed to save using the above structure.

Implemented this on Azure databricks and the code did the trick, starting all available nodes.